# When is it necessary to apply taxes for web freelancing services in Quebec, Canada?

Tags: canada, self-employment, taxes, quebec

When is it necessary to apply taxes for web freelancing services in Quebec, Canada?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there are two kinds of taxes your web freelancing income may be subject to in Quebec:

- **income taxes**, and
- **sales taxes** (GST & QST)

On the income taxes:  The net income you realize from your web freelancing activities would be considered taxable income.  Assuming you are not operating as an incorporated business, you would need to declare the freelancing income on both your federal and provincial tax returns.  You should be able to deduct certain costs related to your business – for instance, if you paid for software, hosting, domain name registration, etc.  That is, only the *profit* from your business would be subject to income tax.  With income and expenses arising from self-employment, you may want to use a professional to file your taxes.

On the sales taxes: You may also need to charge [federal GST and provincial QST (Quebec Sales Tax)](http://www.revenu.gouv.qc.ca/en/entreprise/taxes/tvq_tps/default.aspx) on your services:  You must enroll and charge GST and QST once you exceed the "small supplier" revenue threshold of $30,000 measured over four consecutive quarters.  (You can still *choose* to enroll for GST/QST before you reach that amount, but over that amount enrollment becomes mandatory.  Some businesses enroll before the threshold is reached so they can claim input tax credits for tax paid on expenses, but then there's more paperwork – one reason to perhaps avoid enrolling until necessary.)

In Quebec, the [Ministère du Revenu du Québec](http://www.revenu.gouv.qc.ca/en/default.aspx) administers both GST (on behalf of the federal government) as well as provincial QST.  Be sure to also check out their informative booklet, [Should I Register with Revenu Quebec? (PDF)](http://www.revenuquebec.ca/documents/en/publications/in/in-203-v%282011-05%29.pdf).  See also [General
Information Concerning the QST and the GST/HST (PDF)](http://www.revenuquebec.ca/documents/en/publications/in/in-203-v%282011-05%29.pdf).